# Swift Array of Class Types that Each Conform to a Protocol and are Subclasses of Common Class

Tags: swift

I have a method in Swift with a signature of the form:

`func myMethod<T>(class: T.Type) where T: SomeClass & MyProtocol`

I would like to have a variable that is an array of classes that are all subclasses of SomeClass and conform to MyProtocol.

It would look something like:

`let classArray = [SubclassOfSomeClass.self, SubclassTwoOfSomeClass.self, SubclassThreeOfSomeClass.self]`

Where each of SubclassOfSomeClass, SubclassTwoOfSomeClass and SubclassThreeOfSomeClass conform to MyProtocol

I would then like to call `myMethod` as follows:

```
classArray.forEach { classType in

    myMethod(class: classType)
}
```

I receive the compiler error "Generic parameter T could not be inferred". This makes sense to me as the type of `classArray` variable is inferred as `[MyClass.Type]`.

My question is, can and how do I define the variable `classArray` such that the compiler knows that every type defined therein conforms to the protocol `MyProtocol`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve that by having `SomeClass` conform to `MyProtocol`. Therefore every subclass would also have to conform to `MyProtocol`.

Then your method signature would be just:

```
func myMethod<T>(class: T.Type) where T: SomeClass
```

If that is not desired then you can change the type of myMethod to not be generic. I think swift is unable to type the array to have elements of (SomeClass & MyProtocol).Type. In your case you are not really using a generic object. You do have a specific type in mind and it is `(SomeClass & MyProtocol).Type`. Your code would look something like this:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {

}

class SomeClass: NSObject {

}

class SubClass: SomeClass, MyProtocol {

}

class SubClass2: SomeClass, MyProtocol {

}

let classArray: [(SomeClass & MyProtocol).Type] = [SubClass.self, SubClass2.self]

func myMethod(class: (SomeClass & MyProtocol).Type) {

}

classArray.forEach {
    myMethod(class: $0)
}
```

Comment: That is true, however not all subclasses on SomeClass conform to MyProtocol so this is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: You can check my edit then. I just don't think you can use generics like you are describing.

Comment: Appreciate the effort however `[SubClass(), SubClass2()]` is an array of instances of the classes, not `[SomeClass.Type]`. If generics cannot be used as described, that is a totally acceptable answer.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood. You can do it on the type also. Updated again.

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol MyProtocol {
   var x: Int { get }
}

class MyClass: NSObject {
    var y: Int = 10
}

class SubClass1: MyClass, MyProtocol {
    private(set) var x: Int = 9
}

class SubClass2: MyClass {
}

class SubClass3: MyClass, MyProtocol {
    var x: Int { return 15 }
}

let items: [MyClass & MyProtocol] = [SubClass1(), SubClass3()]

func myMethod(_ item: MyClass & MyProtocol) {}

classArray.forEach { myMethod($0) }
```

So for now you can use just **MyClass & MyProtocol**